# Vertical Variant of Lightning-Tabset Causes Screen Run-off

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-tabset

**tl;dr** - Why is the vertical variant of the lightning-tabset causing screen run-off?

**Description**

My child component renders fine while in a subset of a lightning-tabset, but when I change the lightning-tabset to include the variant='vertical' modifier, the child-component runs off the screen.

Photo 1 is of the component in under a regular lightning-datatable, and photo 2 is under the vertical-variant lightning-datatable.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? I have attempted changing the child component and parent component to include lightning-layouts, have removed and returned floats to the child component, and other HTML tweaks.

**Photo 1**

[image]

**Photo 2**

[image]

**Code**

Parent html

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Intacct Integration">
    <lightning-tabset>
      <lightning-tab label="Exporter">
        <lightning-tabset>
          <lightning-tab label="Payments">
            <c-payment-exporter></c-payment-exporter>
          </lightning-tab>
          <lightning-tab label="Vendors"> </lightning-tab>
        </lightning-tabset>
      </lightning-tab>
      <lightning-tab label="Importer">
        <c-payment-importer></c-payment-importer>
      </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

The child-component code is longer but can be provided if requested.

Comment: It runs off because your component is way bigger to fit in a normal screen width, apply a width to parent div and in child component give overflow parameter to autp and check.

Comment: @NagendraSingh I've tried altering the width on both, but it seems like this issue may be rooted in the lighting-tab lwc library itself. I changed the width of the vertical lighting-tab and a div just within the tab, neither of which had any effect. Limiting the child component width works if I use set pixel sizes, but any percentage based size causes the same overflow error.